# How can I optimize my MySQL query converted from SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I had MS SQL query that used to run really fast, but we moved to MySQL and I have to rebuild the MS SQL query in MySQL, but I ran into some problem since MySQL is not supporting Full Join. I did a work around and it justs keep running (everything is fine until the last join (X), I think this will take forever to load).

How can I improve this query?

SQL query:

```
WITH BadInvoiceCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(P.InvoiceNumber, C.InvoiceNumber) [InvoiceNumber]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            InvoiceNumber
            ,COUNT(SK.Sku) [SkuCount]
        FROM InvoiceDetail ID
            LEFT JOIN tardis.Skus SK ON SK.EntityID = ID.Sku_EntityID
        WHERE SK.Sku IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030')
            AND ID.DivisionID = 3
            AND ID.ActivityDate >=  '2018-02-04'
            AND SK.LevelSix = 'GLASS'
        GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
    ) P
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT 
            InvoiceNumber 
            ,COUNT(SK.Sku) [SkuCount]
        FROM InvoiceDetail ID
            LEFT JOIN tardis.Skus SK ON SK.EntityID = ID.Sku_EntityID
        WHERE SK.Sku IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046')
            AND ID.DivisionID = 3
            AND ID.ActivityDate >=  '2018-02-04'
            AND SK.LevelSix = 'GLASS'
        GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
    ) C ON C.InvoiceNumber = P.InvoiceNumber
    WHERE ISNULL(P.SkuCount,0) <> ISNULL(C.SkuCount,0)
)   

SELECT
    Id.ActivityDate [InvoiceDate]
    ,ID.InvoiceNumber
    ,ST.Store
    ,SK.[Product Description] [ProductName] 
    ,SK.Sku [SKU]
    ,SK.LevelThree
    ,SK.LevelFour
    ,SK.LevelFive
    ,SK.LevelSix
    ,ID.Price
    ,EM.[Name] [SalesPerson]
    , CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(CASE WHEN X.Sku ='BPPRNS000037' AND SK.Sku IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046') THEN ID.Quantity END)) [WarrantyCorrect]
    , CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(CASE WHEN X.Sku ='BPPRNS000029' AND SK.Sku IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046') THEN ID.Quantity END)) [BlackIceInstallErrorCorrect]
    , CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(CASE WHEN X.Sku ='BPPRNS000030' AND SK.Sku IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046') THEN ID.Quantity END)) [DefectiveItem]
FROM
    BadInvoiceCTE BI
    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetail ID ON ID.InvoiceNumber = BI.InvoiceNumber
    LEFT JOIN tardis.Skus SK ON SK.EntityID = ID.Sku_EntityID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Stores ST ON ST.EntityID = ID.Store_EntityID
    LEFT JOIN tardis.Employees EM ON EM.EntityID = ID.Employee_EntityID
    LEFT JOIN   (       
        SELECT 
            InvoiceNumber 
            ,Sku
        FROM InvoiceDetail ID
            LEFT JOIN tardis.Skus SK ON SK.EntityID = ID.Sku_EntityID
        WHERE SK.Sku IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030')
            AND ID.DivisionID = 3
            AND ID.ActivityDate >=  '2018-02-04'
            AND SK.LevelSix = 'GLASS'
    ) X ON X.InvoiceNumber = ID.InvoiceNumber
WHERE
    ID.DivisionID = 3
    AND ID.ActivityDate >=  '2018-02-04'
    AND SK.LevelSix = 'GLASS'
GROUP BY 
     ID.ActivityDate 
    ,ID.InvoiceNumber
    ,ST.Store
    ,SK.[Product Description] 
    ,SK.Sku
    ,SK.LevelThree
    ,SK.LevelFour
    ,SK.LevelFive
    ,SK.LevelSix
    ,ID.Price
    ,EM.[Name]
ORDER BY ID.InvoiceNumber
```

MySQL query that I rebuilt

```
WITH BadInvoiceCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(P.InvoiceIDByStore, C.InvoiceIDByStore) 'InvoiceNumber'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
              P.InvoiceIDByStore
            , COUNT(SK.ID) 'SkuCount'
        FROM 
            simplymacstaging.productdetail P
            LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
        WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
            AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
            AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030')
        GROUP BY  P.InvoiceIDByStore
    ) P
    Left Join (
        SELECT
              P.InvoiceIDByStore
            , COUNT(SK.ID) 'SkuCount'
        FROM 
            simplymacstaging.productdetail P
            LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
        WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
            AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
            AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046')
        GROUP BY  P.InvoiceIDByStore
    ) C ON C.InvoiceIDByStore = P.InvoiceIDByStore
      WHERE ifnull(P.SkuCount,0) <> ifnull(C.SkuCount,0)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(P.InvoiceIDByStore, C.InvoiceIDByStore) 'InvoiceNumber'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
              P.InvoiceIDByStore
            , COUNT(SK.ID) 'SkuCount'
        FROM 
            simplymacstaging.productdetail P
            LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
        WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
            AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
            AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030')
        GROUP BY  P.InvoiceIDByStore
    ) P
    right Join (
        SELECT
              P.InvoiceIDByStore
            , COUNT(SK.ID) 'SkuCount'
        FROM 
            simplymacstaging.productdetail P
            LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
        WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
            AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
            AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046')
        GROUP BY  P.InvoiceIDByStore
    ) C ON C.InvoiceIDByStore = P.InvoiceIDByStore
      WHERE ifnull(P.SkuCount,0) <> ifnull(C.SkuCount,0)
)
SELECT 
      Convert(ID.DateCreated, Date) 'InvoiceDate'
    , ID.InvoiceIDByStore
    , ID.InvoicedAt
    , Sk.Description
    , Sk.ID 'ProductName'
    , SK.Level3
    , SK.Level4
    , SK.Level5
    , SK.Level6
    , ID.TotalPrice
    , ID.EmployeeName
   # , SUM(CASE WHEN X.ID ='BPPRNS000037' AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046') THEN ID.Quantity END) 'WarrantyCorrect'
FROM
    BadInvoiceCTE BI
    INNER JOIN simplymacstaging.productdetail ID ON ID.InvoiceIDByStore = BI.InvoiceNumber
    LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = ID.ProductIdentifier
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          P.InvoiceIDByStore
        , Sk.ID
        FROM
            simplymacstaging.productdetail P
            LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
        WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
            AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
            AND SK.ID IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030')
    ) X ON X.InvoiceIDByStore = ID.InvoiceIDByStore
WHERE
    CONVERT(ID.DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
    AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
GROUP BY
    Convert(ID.DateCreated, Date)
    , ID.InvoiceIDByStore
    , ID.InvoicedAt
    , Sk.Description
    , Sk.ID 
    , SK.Level3
    , SK.Level4
    , SK.Level5
    , SK.Level6
    , ID.TotalPrice
    , ID.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Please read this and pay attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then please [edit] your question to provide more details. That being said, it's a very large query.

Comment: (1) I am guessing you could probably simplify at least some of the stuff in the CTE with conditional aggregation. (2) left joining to X instead of directly to SK seems odd to me

Comment: We'd need to know Mysql version and see table structure for all tables involved before we can even try to make an educated guess about this. There's too many possibilities (missing indexes, flawed optimization plans known on some mysql versions, etc)

Comment: Also, have you tried an `EXPLAIN` on the query? it may help pinpointing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify the whole CTE with conditional aggregation like so:

```
SELECT P.InvoiceIDByStore
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN SK.ID IN ('BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
        ) 'SkuCount1'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN SK.ID IN ('BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
        ) 'SkuCount2'
FROM simplymacstaging.productdetail P
LEFT JOIN simplymacstaging.sku_view Sk ON Sk.ID = P.ProductIdentifier
WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
    AND Sk.Level6 = 'GLASS'
    AND SK.ID IN (
        'BPPRNS000037', 'BPPRNS000029', 'BPPRNS000030'
        , 'BPPRGG000027', 'BPPRGG000026', 'BPPRGG000035', 'BPPRGG000036', 'BPPRGG000045', 'BPPRGG000046'
    )
GROUP BY P.InvoiceIDByStore
HAVING SkuCount1 <> SkuCount2
```

...and to elaborate on what I said in the comment, `LEFT JOIN`ing to "X" (on InvoiceNumber alone), rather than to "SK" directly (on product ident and the WHERE conditions of X) seems like it would form a semi-cross product of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @Uueerdo's answer:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DateCreated, Date) >= '2019-02-03'
```

--> (assuming `DateCreated` is of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`)

```
WHERE DateCreated >= '2019-02-03'
```

And

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN SK.ID IN (...) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
```

--> (more concisely, though non-standard)

```
SUM(SK.ID IN (...))
```

Do you have this composite index?

```
INDEX(Level6, ID, DateCreated??)
```

(If `DateCreated` is not in `Sk`, leave it off)